# Overlay Network on Windows Server 2016 for WSFC + SQL Server HA

Tags: windows-server-2016, openvswitch, docker-swarm, sql-server-cluster

I'm trying to create an **Overlay Network on Windows Server 2016** to create a separate address space for **Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC)**. This cluster will eventually be used to host a **SQL Server HA Cluster**.

**Reason for doing this:**

The 2 windows VMs are hosted with a cloud provider who is unable to provide additional private network interfaces or IP addresses per VM.

**SQL01 (10.5.2.10)

SQL02 (10.5.2.11)**

When a WSFC cluster is created, it needs 1 IP for the cluster.

The SQL Server HA Cluster also requires another IP for the SQL Clustered instance.

Since I don't have the flexibility to create more private IP addresses, the idea is to use an overlay network which will be used on the SQL Clustered instance.

**The Proposed Solution:**

**SQL01** [10.5.2.10] **(192.168.10.10)**  ...  [primary] (overlay)

**SQL02** [10.5.2.11] **(192.168.10.11)**

**WINCLUSTER (192.168.10.20)**

**SQLCLUSTER (192.168.10.30)**

(The web servers would also need interfaces in the same IP range to speak to the cluster.)

I am considering 2 options to achieve this.

1. Overlay Network using Docker Swarm
2. VXLAN using OpenVSwitch (https://cloudbase.it/category/open-vswitch/)

Am able to create a swarm using both the nodes. However, can't seem to figure out how both Docker hosts could communicate with each other, without using containers. Yes, I don't intend to run the SQL Server inside a container. Our current implementation requires SQL Server 2014 Standard.

I would need a virtual interface on each node, which would be assigned private IP address in 192.168.10.0/24

So, each node should be able to speak to one another on this Overlay network, which would ultimately use the underlying 10.5.0.0/22 Network for communication.

Something similar has been attempted using some third party tool which uses OpenVPN in the background. But not comfortable with such a thing for a production environment.

https://cohesive.net/Use+VNS3+to+set+up+Windows+Server+Failover+Clustering+%28WSFC%29+

Can I use Docker/OpenVSwitch to create such a network to achieve Host-Host communication and create a separate address space for WSFC + SQL Clustering?

Has anyone achieved this and production ready? Please point me in the right direction.